# one and only one double root(quartic equation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I want to know how I can determine all positive real values of $b$ for which this equation will have one and only one double root: $x^4 +8x^3 + (288-72b)x^2 + (1088-32b)x + (4b-136)^2 = 0$.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

If [Monic Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonicPolynomial.html) $f(x)$ has exactly one double root $a, f'(a)=0,$

$(f(x),f'(x))=x-a$

Comment: @Shobhit, if $$f(x)=(x-a)^n\cdot g(x), f'(x)=(x-a)^n\cdot g'(x)+n(x-a)^{n-1}\cdot g(x)=(x-a)^{n-1}((x-a)\cdot g'(x)+n\cdot g(x))$$ Here  $n=2$

Comment: @Shobhit, this should help  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140797/how-to-tell-if-a-quartic-equation-has-a-multiple-root

Comment: @Shobhit, have you read lines  "$\triangle= 0,$ at least two equal roots;" and "roots real, two and only two equal"

Answer (score 0):

values satisfying the equations are 9,34.